# Underscore is not working in oracle like clause

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

When development, I used 'test_1%' to find 'test_123' in like. But in production environment its not working. Using 'escape '\'' is working. is there any setting needs to set in oracle? I want to use without escape '\''.

Comment: it is because of that underscore works same as percent in like clause but it refers to just one character.

Comment: I want to search value with underscore without using escape. How to do?

Comment: You have the same string "test_123" in your prod environment, and your query is not able to find it?

Comment: `_` matches any character including `_`, so `test_123` will be found :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

try this in SQL Developer:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME LIKE 'test\_1%' escape '\'
```

in sql plus:

```
set escape '\'
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME LIKE 'test\_1%';
```

Comment: How can this be done in a PLSQL package. When I submit the package for compilation the escape '\' gives me a ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: That `ESCAPE` clause is easy to miss; this answer could do with pointing it out more.

Comment: I wanted to point out something from the Oracle docs that I think is important to know... "If `esc_char` is not specified, then there is no default escape character."

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle, you can also use `ESCAPE` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE description LIKE 'testing\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers using the `ESCAPE '\'` didn't work for me, but I was able to overcome this issue by using a REPLACE function:

```
SELECT * FROM name_of_table WHERE REPLACE(description, '_', '~') LIKE 'testing~%';
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this has worked (using ^ as escape character):

```
select * from all_tables where  table_name  not like '%^_%' escape '^' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using _ as escape character and using double _ in like condition has worked for me.

If you want to add more condition, put ESCAPE keyword after LIKE condition.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%__%' ESCAPE '_' AND ...
```