# How to use special character '_' in where clause of oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I want to get the columns named 'pl_name' contains `_5M_`. So i did following query ,but it is giving all the values but i want `pl_name` like `AR_5M_testclient_986`

Query used is as below

```
select *from mn_table where status='Y' and upper(pl_name) like'%_5M_%'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscore is not working in oracle like clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380261/underscore-is-not-working-in-oracle-like-clause)

Answer (score 1):

The underscore `_` is treated as a wild card in SQL, so it's actually trying to match any character.

In Oracle you can use an escape character to escape special characters:

```sql
select * from mn_table where status='Y' and upper(pl_name) like'%\_5M\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Alternatively, from [Oracle LIKE docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm):

> You can also search for the escape character itself by repeating it.
> For example, if @ is the escape character, then you can use @@ to
> search for @.

```sql
select * from mn_table where status='Y' and upper(pl_name) like'%__5M__%' ESCAPE '_'
```

Answer (score -2):

Treat underscore as a wildcard entry. Use `[_]`.

```
select * from mn_table where status='Y' and upper(pl_name) like '%[_]5M[_]%';
```

Comment: Not in Oracle...