# Using Oracle "starts with" query logic and java PreparedStatement at the same time

Tags: oracle, prepared-statement, startswith

I have an Oracle query:

```
select *
from part
where part_number like 'PDM%'
```

This will result in every part with a part_number that starts with "PDM" (Read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11586236/963076).

I want to execute this query with a Java `PreparedStatement` so that I can replace "PDM" with any text. So, I created this method:

```
String sql = "select * \n" +
    "from part \n" +
    "where part_number like '?%' \n";

try(PreparedStatement p_stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    p_stmt.setString(1, "PDM");

    ResultSet results = p_stmt.executeQuery();

    while(results.next()) {
        System.out.println(results.getString("part_number"));
    }
}
```

However, this results in an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5321)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5309)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:280)
at [my stack trace]
```

The problem, I think, has to do with the fact that the `PreparedStatement` is looking for the question mark `?` to be by itself. But I need the `%` to be present to give me the 'starts with' query logic. So because the `%` is there it's not finding the `?`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Check the duplicate link for your answer.  You need to use `LIKE ?` with `?` serving as just a placeholder.  Then, bind whatever text you want to it.

Answer (score 1):

`?` characters inside string literals are **not** placeholders, and cannot be bound to. You could, instead, have the `?` stand alone and concatenate the `%` character to it using the `||` operator:

```
String sql = "select * \n" +
    "from part \n" +
    "where part_number like ? || '%' \n";
// Here --------------------^
```